# setting up node-supervisor for nodeJS

Tags: node.js

Hi I'm a nodeJS and command line noob. I've managed to get a linux box up running and everything is fine. However restarting the node scripts every time I make changes is beginning to frustrate. 
So I'm trying to set up node supervisor.
https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor

All installed fine but 
when I try to set it up using the following from the command line (putty)

supervisor test.js

I get 
supervisor: command not found

Does anyone have any idea why this would be? 
many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it means supervisor isn't in your path or wasn't set with execute permissions. Find supervisor then use the full path to it. it's possibly still in the build folder if you forgot to install it system-wide.

Comment: thanks - after I use 'npm install supervisor' a 'supervisor' directory appears in the 'node_modules' sub directory for both the 'npm' directory and the 'node' directory. Is there something else I need to go to get it to be available system wide?

Comment: system-wide directories are `/(s)bin`,`/usr/(s)bin` (the sbin variants are for superuser / root). These folders are in the PATH environment variable. You can either put your binary in one of these or add your folder to PATH.

Comment: Note for Homebrew users such as myself - installing npm as part of `brew install node` does not add npm binaries' path to PATH. You'd have to do something like `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've installed it:
    npm install supervisor -g
and I updated my PATH to 
    /usr/local/share/npm/bin/supervisor
and I still get:
    supervisor: command not found

Comment: another way to install it globally is this `npm install -g supervisor`. I think `-g` means 'globally' thought I did not found it in the `--help` output

Answer (score 2):

You should install supervisor globally with -g command option

```
> npm install -g supervisor
```